# What is command prompt's console name?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, console

Is there a "console" in command prompt? There are consoles in browsers, but what about command prompt? I tried console.log, but it didn't understand what "console" meant. I have Windows 7 Professional.
It says:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Command prompt is a command prompt, not a browser.

Comment: you can run js in cmd with Cscript.exe in cmd with `Cscript.exe "C:\..."` and i cant seem to figure out what the object name is for the console in Cscript.exe/Command Prompt

Comment: It's the `cscript` executing JS, not command prompt. The command prompt doesn't *have* a console because it *is* a console. Besides, `cscript` is really old and weird - have a look at [node.js](https://nodejs.org/).

Comment: The command prompt is sometimes called the command console. And web browsers having a "console" is a very recent thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do the analogous thing as JavaScript `console.log()` function use `echo` command to display text on the console screen.